# SSH Agent forwarding not working with Bastion Server, access denied public key Error?

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

`ForwardAgent yes` is configured on the workstation

`AllowAgentForwarding` is set on the sshd.conf file in the bastion

$SSH_AUTH_SOCK contains a path to a file which can neither be deleted nor be opened in any program due to permissions errors (changed permissions to see if things could get back to normal, however that did not work).

contents of the `~/.ssh/config f`ile is below:

```
Host bastion
    Hostname 10.22.105.143
    user myusername
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/myapp3-staging.pem
```

However I am getting access denied public key error when trying to access other machines from the bastion host.  Please see the result of the bastion debug below:

```
$ ssh bastion -Tv

OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/user/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for bastion
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.22.105.143 [10.22.105.143] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/myapp3-staging.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/myapp3-staging.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 10.22.105.143:22 as 'ec2-user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:xMwdmyTxChXwolpH/oDKjs7PObriTFvycACdz9U2QPA
debug1: Host '10.22.105.143' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:6
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: myuser@example.com
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: myuser@example.com
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/myapp3-staging.pem
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 10.22.105.143 ([10.22.105.143]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: Requesting authentication agent forwarding.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_IN
```

Please help me resolve this.

Comment: Check that the corresponding public key is in the user's ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file.  ssh-agent only handles forwarding the private key with the client, not making each server accept a key that has been accepted on a previous hop.

Comment: authorized_keys file is present in both the bastion server and the end nodes that I get access through the bastion, i do not have authorized_keys file in my laptop user though; that is where I log into my bastion box.

I can log into the bastion box without any issues.

Comment: You don't need the authorized_keys file on the client (source host).  Do the authorized_keys file have the public key that corresponds to your private key?  It's not enough for the file just to exist or have random keys in it.

Comment: It does have the corresponding public key for my private key. I am not quite sure why it is behaving like this. It was working earlier without any issue and I don't remember changing anything !

Comment: Output of `ssh-add -l`?

Comment: @KarenB That was the issue ! the file was corrupted.. Thanks for your patience and support..